# req.body пустой объект когда у формы enctype='multipart/form-data'

Tags: node.js, express, fileupload

Есть форма, которая отправляет на сервер как тесктовые поля, так и аплоадит изображения. Использую **formidable** middleware. У формы прописывается аттрибут **enctype='multipart/form-data'**. Проблема в том, что после добавления аттрибута для формы, тело объекта запроса становится пустым: req.body is {}, но при этом изображения аплоадятся. И наоборот, если убрать этот аттрибут, то req.body содержит поля формы, но картинки не аплоадятся. В чём может быть проблема?

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var formidable = require('formidable');   

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){

    console.log(req.body); // is empty

    form.parse(req);    
    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });    
    form.on('file', function (name, file){
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });    
    res.send('sent to server');

});    

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.on('error', function(e){
    console.log(e);
})
server.listen(4000);
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name='name'>
      <input type="file" name='fotos'>
      <button type="sumbit">Отправить</button>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: наверно потому что ты не используешь мидллвару formidable, посмотри в доках, как ее надо использовать. например, боди-парсер `app.use(bodyParser.json());` у тебя может быть, что то типа `app.use(formidable());` и вот это наверно еще надо добавить `var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()`

Comment: согласно доке https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable, formidable не подключается как обычная middleware через use. И да, удалила случайно в вопросе строку инициализации формы var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(). Но трабл всё равно остаётся: тело запроса пустое. Моё ишшью на гитхабе: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/435

Comment: попробуй другие busboy, multer или multiparty

Comment: таки да, multer works. он по умолчанию загружает файлы закодираванные в 7bit, которые надо переименовать, чтоб получить непосредственно файл, сохраненный в папке. спасибо за помощь!